# Batch script - Create folder issue

Tags: batch-file, directory

I'm trying to create a batch script that creates folders based on lines in a text file. I want to be able to automate the "D" function so no typing required.

> @echo off
>
> set /P D="Enter Name e.g. ABCD:"
>
> for /F "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) DO (
>
> FOR  %%x IN (
>
> "C:\test\%D%\%%a"
>
> "C:\test\%D%\%%a\Folder1"
>
> "C:\test\%D%\%%a\Folder2"
>
> ) DO (
>
> MD "%%~x"
>
> )
>
> )

My List file looks like this

> JACK-12345
>
> JOHN-12345

I'm wanting to read the first 4 characters of each line and create directories in relevant folders that already exist.

So JACK-12345 will create a folder in C:\test\JACK\JACK-12345 and JOHN will create a folder C:\test\JOHN\JOHN-12345

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for "the first 4 characters" or are you actually looking for "the part up to the dash"? Both the same from your extensive examples.

Comment: Just first 4 characters, all the folders I'm working with will only be 4 characters (names used in example are probably not the best way to put it as names can be longer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"

for /F "delims=" %%a in (q35285628.txt) DO (
 SET "ch4=%%a"
 SET "ch4=!ch4:~0,4!"
 FOR %%x IN (
  "%targetdir%\!ch4!\%%a"
  "%targetdir%\!ch4!\%%a\Folder1"
  "%targetdir%\!ch4!\%%a\Folder2"
 ) DO (
  ECHO(MD "%%~x"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `targetdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q35285628.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

Invoke `delayedexpansion` to allow substringing of the metavariable `%%a` Assig the entire string as read to `ch4` then select the first 4 characters.

`!var!` required within the block to access the changing value of the variable at run-time.

---

For the extended question (unspecified : where "maths" etc fits into the tree - additional, replacement, whatever??

Using the "meat" of the routine:

```
 SET "ch4=%%a"
 SET "ch4=!ch4:~0,4!"
 SET "folder1=Folder1"
 if /i "!ch4:~0,1!"=="m" SET "folder1=Maths"
 if /i "!ch4:~0,1!"=="s" SET "folder1=Science"
 FOR %%x IN (
  "%targetdir%\!ch4!\%%a"
  "%targetdir%\!ch4!\%%a\!folder1!"
  "%targetdir%\!ch4!\%%a\Folder2"
 ) DO (
  ECHO(MD "%%~x"
 )
)
```

would replace "folder1" from the original scheme with "Maths" if the first character of the line read from the file was "m" (in either case), "Science" if it was "s" and "Folder1" otherwise.

Comment: Works quite well! Thanks Magoo very nice work much appreciated

Comment: If I had a path similar to C:\test\Maths and C:\test\Science

Is there a way to make it by reading the first character it will know to go to "Maths" or "Science" folder? e.g if first character in the txt is S it will go to Science and if its M it will go to Maths?

  "%targetdir%\!ch4!\%%a"
  "%targetdir%\!ch4!\%%a\Folder1"
  "%targetdir%\!ch4!\%%a\Folder2"